# Склонение названия организации при наличии второго родового названия

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение

Имеется название организации *ООО МКК "Сиена"* или *Общество с ограниченной ответственностью микрокредитная компания "Сиена".* Как правильно написать: *решение участника общества с ограниченной ответственностью микрокредитной компании "Сиена"* или *решение участника общества с ограниченной ответственностью микрокрокредитная компания "Сиена"?* То есть склоняется ли второе родовое название, не заключённое в кавычки?

Comment: Решение принято организацией-участником (обществом как участником чего-то) или _участником_ организации?

Comment: участником организации. Это документ, который называется решением. Решение принимается участником общества.

Comment: Может быть, "представителем"? Он ведь там работает и имеет полномочия для принятия решений. Не совсем понятно, как можно  "участвовать" в организации как предприятии. Участие - это обычно что-то кратковременное.

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, раз без кавычек, то можно и нужно склонять. (То, что если бы *МКК Сиена* была полностью в кавычках, тогда бы не склонялось, вижу, Вы и так понимаете.)

Comment: А как при склонении развязаться с сочетанием "участник общества"?

Comment: Не очень понимаю, а что с "участником" не так?

Comment: При склонении полного названия можно понять такой текст двояко: "решение Общества в качестве участника подразумеваемого мероприятия" (как задумано), либо "решение (одного) участника этого Общества".

Comment: Да?! Задумано *решение Общества **в качестве** участника?* Мне такое в голову и не приходило, только второй смысл. А Вы уверены?

Comment: Может, и другой смысл задуман, но прочитать можно про два. Мне показалось более вероятным, что в общем мероприятии участвуют разные организации.

Comment: Хорошо, но для такого смысла нужны знаки препинания какие-то, вот я и воспринял так, как может подразумеваться без них единственно правильно. Надеюсь, автор скажет нам, что имеется в виду.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой *Мне такое в голову и не приходило, только второй смысл*. - А это пресловутый ***многородительный падеж***. У него этих смыслов всегда как гуталина на гуталинной фабрике.

Comment: @behemothus: *...многородительный падеж* — забавно)) *У него этих смыслов всегда как гуталина на гуталинной фабрике.* =)) Кстати, уведомления о комментариях к своему ответу и так приходят, можно и без @.

Comment: *уведомления о комментариях к своему ответу* - ну да, это я переусердствовал. Про цепочки падежей - тут: https://texts.news/literaturovedenie_1041/114-nanizyivanie-padejey-52416.html

Comment: *Дом племянника жены кучера брата доктора* — повеселило.))) Но справедливости ради вроде муж тёти всегда считается дядей, насколько я знаю. Поэтому *жену* можно выкинуть.

Comment: У ООО МКК есть участник (при том единственный), он принимает  решение о чем то. То есть имеется одна организация, участник которой принимает решение - не более того. Пытаюсь доказать ген.директору, что склонять нужно все, что не в кавычках, но он ссылается на официальные документы (решения судов), где склоняется только ООО.

Answer (score 0):

> общества с ограниченной ответственностью микрокредитной компании
>   "Сиена"

Тяжелый случай... 
*Вы точно не запутались в каскаде родительных падежей?* В отличие от английского, в русском языке такой стиль обычно не приветствуется, ибо влечет ошибки понимания.

Итак. По вашему тексту получается, что есть некое безымянное ООО  - и у этого самого общества есть еще некая *микрокредитная организация "Сиена"*? 
Не дай бог придется серьезным юристам это объяснять - так ведь и в суде не докажите, что имелось в виду. Скажу сразу, никакими падежами это не поправить, это семантическая ошибка.

Но, может, все-таки "Сиена" - и есть та самая *"микрокредитная организация"*? 
Тогда фразу необходимо переделывать. 
Первым делом - смотрите как в Уставе это общество называется.
Если там сказано, что зарегистрировано ООО «Микрокредитная компания "Сиена"» то так  и пишите, все вместе - его название и склонять потому не надо. То есть, может, и надо бы, но приводит к совершенно невразумительному тексту.  Поэтому забираем во внешние кавычки, слегка отступая от правил - в пользу здравого смысла.

***Решение участника общества с ограниченной ответственностью «Микрокредитная компания "Сиена"»***

Пусть меня граммарнаци закидают гнилыми помидорами, но этот текст по крайней мере будет понятен даже крючкотвору-юристу.

Правда, я не видел настоящего названия в Уставе - и есть вариант, что я с ним нафантазировал... Но суть моего предложения, надеюсь, понятна.

**UPD**

> Доказываю ген.директору, что правильнее будет склонять, но последний
>   утверждает, "везде пишут так" и значит это правильно. При этом сам
>   читал судебные решения, где суды склоняют только ООО, а МКК не
>   склоняют. Считаю, что это неграмотно

Начальник не прав в плане выбора аргумента. "Все так пишут" - это довод для Инспектора ДПС ("все нарушают!"), здесь надо бы что-то посерьезнее...
Но он прав по сути. Склонять нельзя уже потому, что это приводит к комическим эффектам.

Упростим ситуацию. Возьмём ***Общество фирма "вязанные веники"***.  И что? Предлагает писать (и проищносить!) **Участника общества фирмы "ВВ"**?! Да вас не то что юристы, сами участники засмеют.

Давайте разберемся, что за вид связи в этом словосочетании (ООО ММК).
Виды связи у нас бывают такие: согласование, управление и примыкание. 
При этом только при согласовании требуется **одновременное** изменение падежа. Сложность здесь в том, что два существительных - не типичный пример словосочетания. Но тем не менее вид связи определить довольно просто. Между согласованными членами предложения всегда возможен падежный вопрос. *Мальчик (кто? какой?) Петя.* *Мальчика (кого? какого?) Пети.* - и так далее. Аналогично - для управления, только вопрос этот не изменяется по падежам. *"Команда (чья? какая?) общества "Урожай"", "Команды (чьей? какой?) общества "Урожай""*. При примыкании зависимое слово вообще не требует изменений, а падежный вопрос невозможен. Обычно, правда, зависимое слово и не относится к склоняемым частям речи, но это не обязательное требование. Главное, что невозможен падежный вопрос. Например: **Час (?) пик** или "День Икс"
Конструкция "ООО МКК" полностью аналогична этоткму самому "часу пик" - с той лишь разницей, что у неё именительный падеж зависимого слова (вместо косвенного) - как и в "Дне Икс".

Comment: В уставе общества в кавычки заключено только название - "Сиена". Ранее сиена была просто ООО, но в связи с обязанностью (на законодательном уровне), в название добавлено МКК. У многих организации МКК заключено в кавычки вместе с названием ("МКК Сиена"), а в данном случае в кавычках только название. Доказываю ген.директору, что правильнее будет склонять, но последний утверждает, "везде пишут так" и значит это правильно. При этом сам читал судебные решения, где суды склоняют только ООО, а МКК не склоняют. Считаю, что это неграмотно.

Comment: *Считаю, что это неграмотно.* напрасно. Вы, конечно, можете считать всё, что вам угодно, но на слух дико звучит. Да я, собственно, все это и написал.

Comment: соглашусь, что на слух звучит дико, но это также не аргумент! МКК добавлено в название законом, а не по нашей инициативе. ПОнятно, что в Уставе надо было заключать МКК в кавычки, но этого не сделано.  Пока не вижу аргументов, свидетельствующих в пользу не склонения МКК....